# convert two querys to one in YQL

Tags: yql

can i do JOIN with two querys with yql, i have two querys:

```
select * 
from yahoo.finance.historicaldata 
where symbol in ('YHOO') 
   and startDate='" + startDate + "' 
   and endDate='" + endDate + "'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback="
```

and

```
select symbol, 
       Earnings_per_Share, 
       Dividend_Yield, 
       week_Low, 
       Week_High, 
       Last_Trade_Date, 
       open, 
       low, 
       high, 
       volume, 
       Last_Trade 
from csv where url="http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=YHOO,GOOG&f=seyjkd1oghvl1&e=.csv" 
   and columns="symbol,Earnings_per_Share,Dividend_Yield,Last_Trade_Date,week_Low,Week_High,open,low,high,volume,Last_Trade"
```

i need to convert this two querys to one. how to do this?

Comment: Do you only want to fire one REST call for both queries? Is that your question?

Comment: what i mead is to do table like this:

Comment: http://www.electronics4design.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/priceTable.jpg